# Multiple column scrolling, resizeable panel?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, scrollviewer, wrappanel

I have this:

[image: scrollable panel]

Each list is its own `WrapPanel` and they are all on another `WrapPanel` which is in a `ScrollViewer`.  If I don't set the height myself for the main `WrapPanel` it assumes I want the `WrapPanel` as high as it can go giving me only one column whereas I want as many columns as needed to fill the window.

If I set the `Width` and `Height` of the `WrapPanel` that holds everything to fixed numbers, but I want it to change when the user resizes the window.

Comment: Maybe you should simple change main WrapPanel orientation to horizontal? Then item will be listed not from top to bottom, but from left to right. But everything will look very similar.

Comment: If you want to really leave as it is, then, I think, only option is to create your own version of WrapPanel

Answer (score 0):

In your example screen shot and description I see a tab control whose anchor is set to Top, Left, Bottom, and Right.  The tab page with  AutoScroll set to true.   Within the tab page I see a FlowLayoutPanel.  The FlowLayoutPanel has its AutoSize property set to true. I also see a set of other panels/user controls each of which contains a title and a series of check boxes.

Comment: Are you saying thats what I should do?

Comment: It will give you a similar appearance. I've not tweaked all the settings to ensure it looks 100% like it, but that will get you 90% of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You can`t achieve this with standard controls. You can try to create your own custom WrapPanel implementation. But, actually, looking at original WrapPanel sources I think this will be quite tricky. You see, what you want, is basically to measure how many columns can fit in the current window, while every element in column can be of any size. The way I see that algorithm, it will require N*N iterations to get the final result. So you may have problems with performance.